# Flex col grow to same height as largest

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I've tried a few different iterations of this and just can't figure it out.

I'm using Bootstrap 4.3.1 and have the following div:

```
    <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-8">
            <h3>A lovely header</h3>
            <ul>
                <li>Content</li>
                <li>Content</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 img-wip">
            <p>Hello</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have a `col-8` wide and the 2nd `col-4` wide, the 2nd has a background image defined by the `img-wip` class. The content "Hello" is centered nicely but I can't get the background image to fill to the same height as defined by the content in the left `col-8` column. The `col-4` box just doesn't grow.

I've tried `height:100%` , `flex:1;`, `flex-grow:1;`

But the only thing that would change the height of the background image surrounding `<p>hello</p>` was a specific numerical height. I don't want that, I wanted the height defined by the height of the `col-8`

Is this possible or have I misunderstood how flex works?

The `.img-wip` class resolves to:

```
.img-fill {
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url(../images/resin_wip.jpg);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have understood about **flexbox** is indeed correct but you have some confusions. The default behaviour of flex-items is **stretch** in **cross-axis**.  In your case you are not putting a content within your div with **img-wip** class (`<div class="col-4 img-wip">... </div>`).

You are setting **background-image** in your CSS. And what is happening is that, the height of the **flex-container** is taken as the height of largest of the flex-items (*This is the default behaviour in Flexbox*) and in the code it is your **first column** which is  `<div class="col-8">`.

If you add more content to you col-8 div, you will realize that your image will start to show more and more or If you set a height on **col-4** div to the height of the image, height of  **col-8** div will also increase accordinly

**Another scenario** is directly adding the **img** tag in your **col-4** div. In that case you will see that, full image is shown and **col-8** div also takes the height of the **col-4** div (as expected in flex-box).

CODE SNIPPET shows this behavior:

```css
.img-wip {
  background-image: url("https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1583368215/phone-2_ohtt5s.png");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta
          name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
        />

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
          crossorigin="anonymous"
        />

        <title>Hello, world!</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center">
          <div class="col-8">
            <h3>A lovely header</h3>
            <ul>
              <li>Content</li>
              <li>Content</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4 img-wip">
            <p>Hello</p>
            <img
              src="https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1583368215/phone-2_ohtt5s.png"
              alt=""
            />
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script
          src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
          integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
          crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
        <script
          src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
          integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
          crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
        <script
          src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
          integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
          crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
      </body>
    </html>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CODE FOR OTHER SCENARIO:**  Keep HTML code same as it is and add below CSS.

**CSS:**

```
.img-wip {
 background-image: 
 url("https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1583368215/phone-2_ohtt5s.png");
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 min-height: 60vh;
}
```